# Error in create account in Android studio / Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

My problem is I don´t know why my create account code doesn´t works right, I let here my "Create Account"

```
package rs.studenty.studentylanguage;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private EditText email,password,name;
private Button sign_in, sign_up;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); // important call

    sign_in = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_sign_in_01);
    sign_up = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_sign_up_01);
    name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
    email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);


    //Check if user is already Logged In
    if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() !=null)
    {
        //User Not Logged In
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignIn.class));

    }

    sign_in.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String getemail = email.getText().toString().trim();
            String getpassword = password.getText().toString().trim();
            callsing_in(getemail, getpassword);


        }
    });

    sign_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String getemail = email.getText().toString().trim();
            String getpassword = password.getText().toString().trim();
            callesign_up(getemail,getpassword);


        }
    });


}
//Create Account
private void callesign_up(String email,String password) {


    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d("TESTING", "Sign up sucessfull" + task.isSuccessful());

                    //If sign in falls, display a message to the user. It sign in succeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Signed up failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else
                    {
                        userProfile();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Created Account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("TESTING", "Created Account");
                    }
                }
            });
}

//Set User Display Account
private void userProfile()
{
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if(user!= null)
    {

        UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder().setDisplayName(name.getText().toString().trim())
                //.setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://Example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg")) //here you can set image link also.
                .build();

        user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d("TESTING", "User profile updated");
                        }
                    }
                });




    }



//Now Start Sign In Process
//SignIn Process

private void callsing_in(String email, String password) {

    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d("TESTING", "Sign In Succesful:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.

                    if(!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.v("TESTING", "singInWithEmail:Failed", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignIn.class);
                        finish();
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }
            });


  }
 }
```

I want to let here the LOGCAT error site :

```
5-15 21:11:28.054 27023-27023/? E/appproc: Enhanced Zygote ASLR: 
ro.knox.enhance.zygote.aslr != 1. Enhanced Zygote ASLR is DISABLED!
05-15 21:11:28.241 27023-27023/? E/SemAffinityControl: SemAffinityControl: 
registerfunction enter
05-15 21:11:28.986 3161-4129/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 15106 [2018-05-15 
21:11:28.986]
05-15 21:11:29.265 27042-27042/? E/appproc: Enhanced Zygote ASLR: 
ro.knox.enhance.zygote.aslr != 1. Enhanced Zygote ASLR is DISABLED!
05-15 21:11:29.449 27042-27042/? E/SemAffinityControl: SemAffinityControl:         
registerfunction enter
05-15 21:11:32.236 27056-27056/? E/appproc: Enhanced Zygote ASLR: 
ro.knox.enhance.zygote.aslr != 1. Enhanced Zygote ASLR is DISABLED!
05-15 21:11:32.243 27058-27058/? E/appproc: Enhanced Zygote ASLR: 
ro.knox.enhance.zygote.aslr != 1. Enhanced Zygote ASLR is DISABLED!
05-15 21:11:32.423 27056-27056/? E/SemAffinityControl: SemAffinityControl: 
registerfunction enter
05-15 21:11:32.430 27058-27058/? E/SemAffinityControl: SemAffinityControl: 
registerfunction enter
05-15 21:11:33.187 27081-27081/? E/appproc: Enhanced Zygote ASLR: 
ro.knox.enhance.zygote.aslr != 1. Enhanced Zygote ASLR is DISABLED!
05-15 21:11:33.365 27081-27081/? E/SemAffinityControl: SemAffinityControl: 
registerfunction enter
05-15 21:11:33.456 27093-27093/? E/Zygote: v2
05-15 21:11:33.457 27093-27093/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
05-15 21:11:33.485 27093-27100/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: 
Broken pipe
05-15 21:11:35.487 27093-27093/rs.studenty.studentylanguage 
E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: 
DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
05-15 21:11:35.666 5017-5017/? E/SKBD: za setCurrentInputModule 
mCurrentInputModule index: 19
05-15 21:11:35.684 5017-5017/? E/SKBD: za setCurrentInputModule 
mCurrentInputModule index: 19
05-15 21:11:35.704 5017-5017/? E/SKBD: get previous
05-15 21:11:37.736 5017-5017/? E/KeyboardInfoUtils: getInstance start
sendSIPInformation state:6  isAbstractKeyboardView : true
05-15 21:11:37.737 5017-27166/? E/KeyboardInfoUtils: sending null 
keyboardInfo as SIP is closed
05-15 21:11:37.807 5017-5017/? E/SKBD: za setCurrentInputModule 
mCurrentInputModule index: 19
05-15 21:11:37.828 5017-5017/? E/SKBD: za setCurrentInputModule 
mCurrentInputModule index: 19
05-15 21:11:40.891 5017-5017/? E/KeyboardInfoUtils: getInstance start
sendSIPInformation state:6  isAbstractKeyboardView : true
05-15 21:11:40.892 5017-27191/? E/KeyboardInfoUtils: sending null 
keyboardInfo as SIP is closed
05-15 21:11:40.963 5017-5017/? E/SKBD: za setCurrentInputModule 
mCurrentInputModule index: 19
05-15 21:11:40.982 5017-5017/? E/SKBD: za setCurrentInputModule 
mCurrentInputModule index: 19
05-15 21:11:44.094 3161-13609/? E/InputMethodManagerService: Perflock object 
null
05-15 21:11:44.097 5017-5017/? E/KeyboardInfoUtils: getInstance start
sendSIPInformation state:6  isAbstractKeyboardView : true
05-15 21:11:44.098 5017-27218/? E/KeyboardInfoUtils: sending null 
keyboardInfo as SIP is closed
05-15 21:11:44.146 5017-5017/? E/SKBD: processWhenPickSuggestionManually : 
32
05-15 21:11:45.073 11025-18394/? E/Volley: [74438] 
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for 
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser? 
alt=proto&key=AIzaSyB5sv1PmXW5F0zytedxMuuCNmaaGggfFqg
05-15 21:11:45.130 11025-18394/? E/Volley: [74438] 
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 
for 
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser? 
alt=proto&key=AIzaSyB5sv1PmXW5F0zytedxMuuCNmaaGggfFqg
```

and here we have the android manifest source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="rs.studenty.studentylanguage">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
   </activity>

   <activity android:name=".SignIn" />

</application>
```

If anyone can helps me that was amazing because I´m new. i was trying hard fix this problem but I can´t so nooby .....

Thanks all what try to fix this problem :)

Comment: "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance it is the system level log of your device's firmware, which was not removed by the device ,manufacturers you can ignore this error.can you please post some more error log if you have

Comment: okey i have copied all the LOGCAT error site

Comment: okay thank let me check

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not have any issue, you have to just go to Firebase account -> open your application -> Click on third tab Authentication and enable signin with email and password and then try

becuase with email and password registration you need to enable the option please find attached screen[image]

Comment: because i have tested you same code and it is working fine, it is creating account in the fire base, you can also check whether any permission needed or which version are you using for firebase auth?

Comment: Permission i use: INTERNET, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE AND READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Firebase auth : 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'

Comment: can be the problem any wifi acess permission or something so? and im using a real test device not emulator

Comment: the version seems fine becuase i use 11.0.4 before and i changes it to 11.6.0 and it also working fine nothing is problem , might be possible to network issues you can check with you mobile data and if possible then can you post the whole class that are you using

Comment: mmmm okey i pasted now the complet class

Comment: is your class have issues?, or it run success? and please check if the below permission is missing if not added then add please                            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

Comment: how i can check that?

Comment: in your android manifest just the above permission if not added because the only thing remain to add, rather you calss is seems fine

Comment: below read external storage permission past the below and check before check uninstall application then try   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

Comment: dont work, one ask for use firebase u need some internet ports open?

Comment: internet ports open? what you mean by?

Comment: can be the problem with the digital fingerprint sha1?

Comment: can you try to give me a source code downloading from a basic firebase login?